# Add multiple ranges in a chart object

Tags: excel, vba

I want to add multiple range to a chart object so to have a chart with multiple data series. Like in below code I need to add rng2, rng3 in the same chart. Need to do that with this specific codding format. 
your help is much appreciated.

```
Sub plt()
Set rng1 = ActiveSheet.Range("A:A,B:B")
With ActiveSheet
  .Shapes.AddChart
  Set objChrt = .ChartObjects(.ChartObjects.Count)
  Set chrt = objChrt.Chart
  With chrt
    .ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
    .SetSourceData Source:=rng1
 End With
End With   
End Sub
```

Comment: I guess you'll have to look into using [`SeriesCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.seriescollection)

Comment: Where is the data located for each range?

Comment: @Domenic what do you mean?

Comment: I meant in which cells in your worksheet is the data located?  rng1 is located in Range("A:A,B:B"), what about rng2, rng3, etc?

Comment: @Domenic rng2 and rng3 are also taken from the same table.